# Can I not use embedded <style> CSS on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, web-applications

I'm debugging a site on an Android HTC Sense. The site uses a lot of inserted content, which comes along with it's own CSS and JS like:

```
// wrapper id = snippet_id
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   #snippet_id div {border: 1px solid red !important;}
   div {border: 1px solid blue !important;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div>Hello World</div>
</body>
<html>
```

This is inserted into an existing page, so it sort these snippets are sort of like iFrames I guess.

**Question:**
Problem is, that while Javascript works fine, all CSS I'm specifying using `<style>` tags is being ignored. Any idea why?

**EDIT:**
Works on:
- Android 4.0.1
Does not work on:
- Android 2.3.1
- IOS 4.1

If I add the CSS to the main.css file being requested when the page loads, all is ok. If it's inside my gadget, it's not working.

**EDIT**:
So from what I can see, `<style>` does not seem to work on classes and id. If I use regular HTML elements as selectors it works.

**EDIT**: 
My dev-site is [here](http://www.franckreich.de/members/export/z/p/index.html). I'm using a plugin called [renderJs](http://www.renderjs.org/), which encapsultes HTML snippets (along with their CSS and JS) into resuable gadgets. Gadgets content will be appended to the page body, so although a gadget can act as a standalone HTML page, it can also be part of a page.

Example code from my page (I stripped out all gadgets but one below):

[index.html](http://www.franckreich.de/members/export/z/p/index.html) - include `index_wrapper` gadget

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" lang="en"  class="render"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/overrides.css">
    <script data-main="../js/main.js" type="text/javascript" src="../js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="splash">
  <div data-role="page" id="index">
      <div id="index_wrapper" data-gadget="../gadgets/index_wrapper.html"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page has a gadget called `index_wrapper` [link](http://www.franckreich.de/members/export/z/gadgets/index_wrapper.html) - code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="index_social" data-gadget="../gadgets/social.html"></div>
   <p class="mini t" data-i18n="gen.disclaimer"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Which has another gadget called `social` [here](http://www.franckreich.de/members/export/z/gadgets/social.html). This gadget includes some CSS, but on the devices in question, it is ignored (just saw, I'm missing a `</div>` in the index_wrapper, so trying to see if that fixed the problem, too).

The code below includes my fix:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
    <style type="text/css" scoped>
    // will be ignroed
    .el {width: 1px;}
    .menu_social {text-align: center; margin: 1em 0;}
    .action_menu {display: inline-block;}
    .follow_us {display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0 .5em 0 0;}
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="menu_social">
    <div>
      <span class="el ui-hidden-accessible"></span><!-- fallback for CSS not working -->
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-theme="c" class="action_menu">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/nexedi" data-ajax="false" id="follow_twitter" data-role="button" data-icon="tw" data-theme="c" class="t ui-icon-vendor twitter scale-a" data-i18n-target=".ui-btn-text" data-i18n="[title]soc.tw_fw;[html]soc.tw"></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Nexedi/168462169880320" data-ajax="false" id="follow_facebook" data-role="button" data-icon="fb" data-theme="c" class="t ui-icon-vendor facebook scale-a" data-i18n-target=".ui-btn-text" data-i18n="[title]soc.fb_fw;[html]soc.fb"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  (function () {
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var gadget = RenderJs.getSelfGadget();

      // fallback for old devices which cannot load <style> css
      if (gadget.dom.find(".el").css('width') !== "1px") {
        require(['text!../css/social.css'], function (t) {
          var x = '<style>'+t+'</style>';
          gadget.dom.append(x);
        });
      }

      // trigger enhancement
      $(this).trigger("render_enhance", {gadget: gadget.dom});
    });
  })();
  //]]>
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

So aside from probably missing a closing `</div>` I'm still wondering why my embedded CSS is not working.

Comment: </head> is not closed....

Comment: "Does not work on: - Android 2.3.1 - IOS 4.1" - which browsers?.. most likely the browser was too crap at that time?

Comment: yeah, can you specific the browser you used for testing? on android

Comment: @d'alar'cop: built-in browsers. Let me check if there is a version to be found

Comment: That's not inline by the way. it's embedded css

Comment: Please post a complete document and/or its URL that actually demonstrates the issue. The code posted does not. From the verbal description, it seems that you are inserting an HTML document inside an HTML document. This would be invalid in a serious way, and browsers should not be expected to do anything sensible with it. Using `iframe` would be a different thing. But we need to see the code that really raises the issue.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: posted above. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the generated HTML code (i.e., code as modified by JavaScript) of the demo page suggests that `style` elements are generated inside `body`. Although such elements are allowed by HTML5 drafts when the `scoped` attribute is present, support to that attribute seems to be nonexistent, and the style sheet is applied globally. It is possible however that some browsers do not apply it at all, at least when the `style` element is dynamically generated.

A better approach is to make all style sheets global to the document, preferably as external style sheets, and use contextual selectors to limit the rules to some elements only. And possibly using JavaScript to change classes of elements, rather than manipulating style sheets directly.

Comment: true. Took me a while to find out about `scoped`. Still the idea is to encapsulate everything related to a gadget, so this would include it's CSS and JS. I'm still playing around with it so I might try using external files vs embedded per gadget, but I'm already looking at a ton of HTTP requests :-) Anyway. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Ugly workaround:

In the inline section, set this:

```
<style>
.el {width: 1px;}
</style>
```

In the page, set hide an element `el` like this:

```
// ui-hidden-accessible is a JQM class, moving the item out of view
// since it uses pos:absolute, &nbsp; is needed to not break
// selects on the page (compare to JQM ui-icon)
<span class="el ui-hidden-accessible">&nbsp;</span>
```

Then check for the width when running inline Javascript (which works) and require the inline CSS as a separate file, when the width is not at `1px`

```
// fallback for old devices which cannot load <style> css
// gadget is my iframe-look-a-like
if (gadget.dom.find(".el").css('width') !== "1px") {
    require(['text!../css/translate.css'], function (t) {
        var x = '<style>'+t+'</style>';
        gadget.dom.append(x);
    });
}
```

Ugly and an extra HTTP request, but at least the CSS is working then.